# Select option by value and change attribute of a selected option

Tags: javascript, html, select

So what I want is to automatically select options in *SELECT_1* and *SELECT_2* by clicking radio (Yes or No) and set the *selected* attribute to those options in *SELECT_1* and *SELECT_2*

What I have is:

```js
function selectThis (){
                var crytRadioYes = document.getElementById("cryteria_yes");
                var crytRadioNo = document.getElementById("cryteria_no");
                var selects = document.getElementById("slctbox");

                if (crytRadioYes.checked == true){
                    selects.value = "Good";
                } else {
                    selects.value = "Bad";
                }

                if (crytRadioNo.checked == true){
                    selects.value = "Bad";
                } else {
                    selects.value = "Good";
                }
            }
```

```html
<table>
                <!-- choose -->
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 15%;"><label><input type="radio" name="cb_Cryteria" id="cryteria_yes" onclick="selectThis()" />Yes</label></td>
                    <td style="width: 15%;"><label><input type="radio" name="cb_Cryteria" id="cryteria_no" onclick="selectThis()" />No</label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <!-- SELECT_1 -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Cryteria 1</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="slctbox">
                            <option value="-">-</option>
                            <option value="Good">Good</option>
                            <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- SELECT_2 -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Cryteria 2</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="slctbox">
                            <option value="-">-</option>
                            <option value="Good">Good</option>
                            <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

As u see it changes value of *SELECT_1* by clicking radio, but does not change the value in *SELECT_2*.
I also dont know how to set attribute "selected"

please help :(

Comment: `id` attribute needs to be unique..

Answer (score 1):

> By definition, [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute needs to be unique.

Simple workaround is to use `class` attribute and loop over elements having the specified class.

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get the list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

```js
function selectThis() {
  var crytRadioYes = document.getElementById("cryteria_yes");
  var crytRadioNo = document.getElementById("cryteria_no");
  var selects = document.querySelectorAll(".slctbox");

  if (crytRadioYes.checked == true) {
    selects.forEach(sel => sel.value = "Good");
  } else {
    selects.forEach(sel => sel.value = "Bad");
  }

  if (crytRadioNo.checked == true) {
    selects.forEach(sel => sel.value = "Bad");
  } else {
    selects.forEach(sel => sel.value = "Good");
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <!-- choose -->
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 15%;"><label><input type="radio" name="cb_Cryteria" id="cryteria_yes" onclick="selectThis()" />Yes</label></td>
    <td style="width: 15%;"><label><input type="radio" name="cb_Cryteria" id="cryteria_no" onclick="selectThis()" />No</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <!-- SELECT_1 -->
  <tr>
    <td>Cryteria 1</td>
    <td>
      <select class="slctbox">
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="Good">Good</option>
        <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- SELECT_2 -->
  <tr>
    <td>Cryteria 2</td>
    <td>
      <select class="slctbox">
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="Good">Good</option>
        <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, and now how Can I set attribute "selected" to "selected" for those options?

Comment: @Matthew - You don't need to. If you want to access the value, use `SELECT_ELEMENT.value`